# Can't bind script to new elements in the DOM

Tags: javascript, ajax, bind

So I've working on this for a while, but I still can't seem to figure it out.

I have a page here: http://taste.fourseasons.com/ingredients/

The show more button at the bottom calls extra posts on to the page with the following script:

```
$("a.view-more").bind('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if($('.post-holder').hasClass('ingredients')) { posttype = 'ingredient'; }
        if($('.post-holder').hasClass('recipe')) { posttype = 'recipe'; }
        if($('.post-holder').hasClass('cmed')) { posttype = 'cmed'; }
        filter = 'none';
        morePosts(posttype,filter);
});
```

And the option to let people vote works with this:

```
$.post('http://taste.fourseasons.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', data,
           function(response){
                   if(response!="-1") {
                           el.find('.vote-sm').removeClass('vote-sm').addClass('unvote-sm');
                           el.find('.vote-text').html("VOTED");
                           el.unbind("click");
                           if(response!="null") {
                                   el.find(".vote-count").html(response);
                           }
                           var cookie = getCookie("better_votes_"+postID);
                           if(!cookie) {
                                   var newcookie = postID;
                           } else {
                                   var newcookie = postID;
                           }
                           setCookie("better_votes_"+postID, newcookie, 365);
                   } else {
                   }
           });
           return false;
   });
```

But when the user clicks show more and those elements are added to the DOM, the vote options isn't working with those new elements. I assumed I could just add them together:

```
$("a.view-more").bind('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if($('.post-holder').hasClass('ingredients')) { posttype = 'ingredient'; }
        if($('.post-holder').hasClass('recipe')) { posttype = 'recipe'; }
        if($('.post-holder').hasClass('cmed')) { posttype = 'cmed'; }
        filter = 'none';
        morePosts(posttype,filter);

        $(".vote").bind('click',function(event) {
               event.preventDefault();
               postID = $(this).attr('data-post');
               var el = $(this);
               //el.html('<span id="loader"></span>');
               var nonce = $("input#voting_nonce_"+postID).val();
               var data = {
                       action: 'add_votes_options',
                       nonce: nonce,
                       postid: postID,
                       ip: '66.252.149.82'                        
               };
               $.post('http://taste.fourseasons.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', data,
               function(response){
                       if(response!="-1") {
                               el.find('.vote-sm').removeClass('vote-sm').addClass('unvote-sm');
                               el.find('.vote-text').html("VOTED");
                               el.unbind("click");
                               if(response!="null") {
                                       el.find(".vote-count").html(response);
                               }
                               var cookie = getCookie("better_votes_"+postID);
                               if(!cookie) {
                                       var newcookie = postID;
                               } else {
                                       var newcookie = postID;
                               }
                               setCookie("better_votes_"+postID, newcookie, 365);
                       } else {
                       }
               });
               return false;
       });
    });
```

But that doesn't seem to work and also creates a scenario that adds two votes to the sum instead of one, every time you vote.

Thanks for any help.

This code is from the wp-function page:

```
function add_votes_options() {
    $postid = $_POST['postid'];
    $ip = $_POST['ip'];

    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce'], 'voting_nonce_'.$postid))
        return;

    $voter_ips = get_post_meta($postid, "voter_ips", true);
    if(!empty($voter_ips) && in_array($ip, $voter_ips)) {
        echo "null";
        die(0);
    } else {
        $voter_ips[] = $ip;
        update_post_meta($postid, "voter_ips", $voter_ips);
    }   

    $current_votes = get_post_meta($postid, "votes", true);
    $new_votes = intval($current_votes) + 1;
    update_post_meta($postid, "votes", $new_votes);
    $return = $new_votes>1 ? $new_votes : $new_votes;
    echo $return;
    die(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've run into a fairly common issue with event binding.

```
$("a.view-more").bind('click',function(event){
```

The above line of code that you wrote attaches an event listener to the DOM elements available at that time. This is why the new elements added to the DOM do not respond to the event; because they don't have the event listener attached.

To work around this we can use something called event delegation. This works by attaching the event to a parent of the DOM elements that you wanted to listen for the event on. We can then work out which child the event started on when the event eventually propagates to the parent.

jQuery makes this very easy to do. You can use the `delegate()` method but I suggest you use the `on()` method which is the method that handles all event operations in jQuery. The others such as `click()`, `mouseover()` and `bind()` are just aliases of `on()`

Anyway, to delegate an event we need to specify a selector for the parent which the event will attach to, and a selector for the elements we are actually interested in. So that line of code will now look like this:

```
$("body").on('click', "a.view-more", function(event){
```

You should really use something other than body but this is just an example.

Further reading: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thanks @Ryan unfortunately this hasn't seemed to work, but perhaps I didn't execute it properly. Changing that line of the view more script to what you have suggested made no difference. By using the delegate() method it actually disabled it.

Comment: @EricBrockman Firstly, have you got any javascript errors, and what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I'm using 1.8.0 As for errors, I'm not sure, I guess I should bring the main js files into jslint or something.

Comment: You can see javascript errors by opening the console in your browser. If you're using Chrome, press ctrl + shift + i to open the developer tools and then click on the console tab.

Comment: I've had a look at the website. The "show more" is half working now. It is making the ajax request to the server to fetch more content. But as it loads a second lot of content, all the server is sending is some javascript. You don't really won't to be fetching and loading the same javascript with each ajax request. However, this is getting onto a whole other issue than the current one.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24082/discussion-between-ryan-and-eric-brockman)

Comment: I just realized that there was a another piece of the puzzle that may take care of that nonce issue, see edited part above.

Comment: I think the problem is with another area that isn't generating the nonce with the ajax request for new content. For a quick fix you could remove this line of code `if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce'], 'voting_nonce_'.$postid)) return;`. That would make it less secure though.